# Google anaytics for AMP - social variables

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

How would I add multiple social values to AMP analytics json properties.

```
"vars": {
          "socialNetwork": "twitter",
          "socialAction": "tweet",
          "socialTarget": "https://www.examplepetstore.com",
          "socialNetwork": "facebook",
          "socialAction": "share"
      }
```

This is what I'm thinking of but I think it's incorrect.
thanks very much!

Comment: The format is good however the events might be more specific to your application i.e pageview, clicks etc. You can always run some Test and see if there is any error message. Debugging this code is also important pointer for what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

**ADD JS**

```
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics"
src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

**Tracking code of Twitter and Facebook**

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackClickOnTwitterLink" : {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "#tweet-link",
      "request": "social",
      "vars": {
          "socialNetwork": "twitter",
          "socialAction": "tweet",
          "socialTarget": "https://www.examplepetstore.com"
      }
    },
    "trackClickOnFacebookLink" : {
      "on": "click",
      "selector": "#facebook-link",
      "request": "social",
      "vars": {
          "socialNetwork": "facebook",
          "socialAction": "facebook",
          "socialTarget": "https://www.examplepetstore.com"
      }
    }

  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Comment: Thanks Bachcha, this is implementation is more clear to me now. Much appreciated!

Comment: @dar I am glad it helps you, kindly accept the answer which help the other community member